# Firebase Firestore & Dialogflow - PROTOBUF Error

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, dialogflow-es

First post here. I need some help and I hope to provide all the information required.

I am trying to integrate DialogFlow to my Android application(Java) where I am using Firebase-Firestore. After completing everything I get the following error.

- Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules

1. jetified-proto-google-common-protos-2.0.1 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.0.1)
2. jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.1.1-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.1.1)

Build.Gradle:

```
// Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.2'

// DialogFlow
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:2.5.0'
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.36.0'
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.36.0'
compileOnly 'org.apache.tomcat:annotations-api:6.0.53'
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.36.0'
```

I have tried this and other combinations too. DialogFlow works fine but Firebase Firestore stops working.

```
configurations 
{
compile.exclude module: 'protolite-well-known-types'
compile.exclude module: 'protolite-proto-google-common-protos'
compile.exclude module: 'protobuf-javalite'
}
```

I am aware that this issue has been asked previously [HERE](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2165) but it has not been resolved.

I have tried adding the plugin and several other solutions but they don't seem to be compatible.

```
plugins {
...
id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.15'
}
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you resolved this?